How can I test expired auth token handing using Firebase Emulator Suite
I have an app that uses Firebase Auth to authenticate users. I have a Web UI built in React (typescript). My backend is Node JS. In development, I am running Firebase Emulator Suite. The auth implementation is working as expected.
I am installing handling for expired auth tokens in the UI. According to Firebase Documentation - Manage Sessions, "Firebase ID tokens are short lived and last for an hour; the refresh token can be used to retrieve new ID tokens.":
The trouble I am having is testing expired tokens in dev. I have not found a way to manually cause a token to expire to test my token refresh implementation, apart from waiting one hour for the token to expire.
Is there a way to simulate expired Firebase Auth tokens in development while using Firebase Emulator Suite?

There might not be.  You should consider filing an issue on firebase-tools and explain what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  (It doesn't work for me either.)

"I have not found a way to manually cause a token to expire" An ID token cannot be modified once it's been minted, so it cannot be retroactively made to expire early.
